# Get the key of a new Entity in Google Cloud DataStore and PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, datastore

In the documentation of DataStore this example is mentioned:

```
$task = $datastore->entity('Task', [
    'category' => 'Personal',
    'done' => false,
    'priority' => 4,
    'description' => 'Learn Cloud Datastore'
]);
$datastore->insert($task);
```

I would like to get the key of this new entity that has just been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a statement similar to: {const taskKey = datastore.key('Task');}

More detail is to be found in the [Retrieving an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity) sub-chapter.